# "Unable to get workspace root" when exporting Eclipse plug-ins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I am writing an Eclipse plug-in and trying to package and export it. In Eclipse, I used File -> Export... -> Deployable plug-ins ans fragments -> Select my plug-in and set the Directory. But it shows the following error:

```
'Export Plug-ins' has encountered a problem.
An internal error occurred during: "Export Plug-ins".
Unable to get workspace root
```

This error has been shown every time even when I try to export an hello world plug-in. What causes this error and what is the correct step to configure and export the plug-in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Getting workspace root errors are mostly related to resources plugin, try adding org.eclipse.core.resources plugin as a dependency and try exporting again. If you can give more detail about the problem we can be more helpful.

Comment: I tried to add org.eclipse.core.resources as dependency but there is still the same problem. Here is the detail about how I set up a simplest plug-in:

Comment: 1. Create a new Plug-in project in eclipse

2. Add org.eclipse.core.runtime and org.eclipse.core.resources as dependency

3. Add a new extension org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications and modify the plugin.xml:

4. Add Application.java and implement org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication interface

5. Select the plugin -> Run as -> Eclipse Application, run successfully in Eclipse.

6. File -> Export... -> Deployable plug-ins and fragments -> select my plugin and directory

Then the export failed. The information is as described in the question.

Comment: Here is my plugin.xml:
`
<plugin>
   <extension
         id="application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application
            cardinality="singleton-global"
            thread="main"
            visible="true">
            <run class="com.test.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
</plugin>
`